# How to query MAX(SUM(relation)) in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have read several related threads on StackOverflow but none of them solves my problem.
I have a **Sales** database as where I need to query for the customer who spent the most amount in buying stuff.
For that, I need to find who bought which product using

```
SELECT  sum(qty*rate) 
AS exp from salesdetails as s JOIN sales as ss on (ss.invno = s.invno) 
JOIN customer as c ON (ss.customerno = c.custno) GROUP BY(c.name) 
ORDER BY sum(qty*rate);
```

It returns a table with the name of the person and what he spent in ascending order as

**Output of command above:**

[image]

While what I actually need is to only print a tuple when `sum(qty*rate)` is maximum. Currently I'm getting the results by sub querying like:

```
SELECT name, sum(qty*rate) FROM salesdetails as s JOIN sales as ss on (ss.invno=s.invno) 
JOIN customer as c ON (ss.customerno = c.custno) GROUP BY(c.name) 
HAVING sum(qty*rate) IN (SELECT max(exp) FROM (SELECT  sum(qty*rate) 
AS exp from salesdetails as s JOIN sales as ss on (ss.invno = s.invno) 
JOIN customer as c ON (ss.customerno = c.custno) GROUP BY(c.name) ORDER BY sum(qty*rate)) aa);
```

Expected Output:

[image]

Is there any shorter way to get to the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
select * 
from (
       SELECT c.Name, sum(qty*rate) 
       AS exp from salesdetails as s JOIN sales as ss on (ss.invno = s.invno) 
       JOIN customer as c ON (ss.customerno = c.custno) 
       GROUP BY(c.name) 
       ORDER BY sum(qty*rate) desc
     ) t
limit 1;
```

Comment: It gave the following error:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 1: select top 1 * 
                   ^

Comment: Edited the answer. Could u please try again? @AashutoshRathi

Comment: It gives 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 6:        ORDER BY sum(qty*rate) desc;
now.
also, you have to add a semicolon at end.

Comment: Maybe now, removed the semi-colon after desc and added it to the end? @AashutoshRathi

Comment: It returns only the value of money spent, I also need to add a column of Name, please check the question's expected output again.

Comment: The columns you want to see in your output, you can add them in the select clause of the subquery. Edited answer. @AashutoshRathi

Comment: Thanks it saved my day.

Comment: There is no good reason to use a subquery here. And ORDER BY in a subquery is not standard complient.

Answer (score 1):

You want `row_number()` or `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.name) c.name, sum(qty*rate) AS exp
FROM salesdetails s JOIN
     sales ss
     on (ss.invno = s.invno) JOIN
     customer c
     ON (ss.customerno = c.custno)
GROUP BY c.name
ORDER BY c.name, sum(qty*rate) DESC;
```

Comment: It gives the whole table, I just need the one who spent most.